# Java Swing Huge Grid

Tags: java, arrays, swing, grid

I'm making a new game that generates a huge grid (lets say 1000x1000). The player starts in the middle and moves around looking for "points". The player can only see a portion of the larger grid in the window (15x15). Right now I just have a huge array of rectangles each that paint a bufferedimage of a dirt block that I created. Question: Is there a better variable type I should be using to store all these images?

This is what my Dirt class looks like (holds the rect, and the image which is generated at the beginning):

```
public class Dirt extends Spot{
    private int index;

    public Dirt(int temp){
        index = temp;
    }

    public Image getImageIndex(){return index;}
}
```

And here is apart of my Board class that draws all the Dirt:

```
public class Board extends JPanel{
    private final int BLOCK_SIZE;                                   //Holds the size of each block
    private final int SIZE;                                     //Holds the size of the board
    private DirtImages[] imgs_Dirt = new DirtImages[20];    //Holds 20 random dirt images - generated at begtinning

    private Spot[][] spots;

    public Board(int size, int blocksize){
        SIZE = size;
        BLOCK_SIZE = blocksize;
        //Board
        setSize(SIZE,SIZE);
        //Timer Label
        add(JTimerLabel.getInstance());

        //Create 20 random Images of dirt to use for the rest of dirts
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            imgs_Dirt[i] = new DirtImages(new Rectangle(0,0,BLOCK_SIZE,BLOCK_SIZE));
            add(imgs_Dirt[i]);
        }

        //Create Dirt
        spots = new Dirt[500][500];
        java.util.Random randomGenerator = new java.util.Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < spots.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < spots.length; j++)
                spots[i][j] = new Dirt(randomGenerator.nextInt(20));
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        //Draw Grid #First
        for(int i = 0; i < spots.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < spots.length; j++)
                if(spots[i][j] != null)
                    g2d.drawImage(imgs_Dirt[((Dirt)spots[i][j]).getImageIndex()].getImage(), BLOCK_SIZE*i,BLOCK_SIZE*j,BLOCK_SIZE,BLOCK_SIZE, null);
        }

        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        g2d.dispose();
        requestFocus();
    }
```

Just to clarify. I create 20 Dirt images so that the dirt (when painted) don't look like they're tiled but are random. So in my array of Dirt, each Dirt points to a random image.

Additional Question: Now that I create my huge grid, how would I make it so the player starts at the center and I draw the surrounding cells. Currently I start at the beggining of the array in the top left corner of my array. Should I create a boolean flag for each dirt of whether or not it should be drawn?

Comment: If it is the same dirt block, keep one instance and paint it as & where needed.  BTW - for `JPanel` override `paintComponent(Graphics)` rather than `paint(Graphics)`

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Or create a grid of JLabel and populate with ImageIcons -- which are allowed to be shared amongst JLabels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have 1,000,000 Dirts and only 20 images, it's kind of a waste to store an image in each dirt.  You can use an index instead.  So to draw, instead of drawing

```
((Dirt)spots[i][j]).getImage()
```

you would draw

```
imgsDirt[((Dirt)spots[i][j]).getImageIndex()]
```

For the updated question:

You seem to be drawing your whole grid(0-1000,0-1000).  What you really want is just to paint the 15x15 'viweable' area.  So instead of

```
    //Draw Grid #First
    for(int i = 0; i < spots.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < spots.length; j++)
```

it would be

```
    //Draw Grid #First
    for(int i = player.xpos-7; i < player.xpos+7; i++){
        for(int j = player.ypos - 7; j < player.ypos+7; j++)
```

You would need an appropriate shift in your drawImage method to make sure it still starts drawing at the upper left of your window.

Comment: in addition to that, why does each instance need to store a rectangle? they are tiles... all the same size

Comment: Now I just need to figure out why everytime I call the repaint method, the Dirt images change their pattern...

Comment: because you've overrided your paint method and put the initialisation code in there? and using Thomas example code exactly as hes written it for you, you are effectively, randomly adding an image to each box

Comment: Well, I generate 20 random images in the board constructor. Then I assign each dirt an imageindex. When I paint i only call each Dirt's image that it's pointing to. I don't see why my paint method would be randomizing the images... but that's what it seems like it is doing.

Comment: Yes that's what I was looking for. It all makes sense now. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

put all those together, and with determine visible `JComponents` in the `JViewPort`

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TilePainter extends JPanel implements Scrollable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tiles");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(new TilePainter()));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    private final int TILE_SIZE = 50;
    private final int TILE_COUNT = 100;
    private final int visibleTiles = 10;
    private final boolean[][] loaded;
    private final boolean[][] loading;
    private final Random random;

    public TilePainter() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(TILE_SIZE * TILE_COUNT, TILE_SIZE * TILE_COUNT));
        loaded = new boolean[TILE_COUNT][TILE_COUNT];
        loading = new boolean[TILE_COUNT][TILE_COUNT];
        random = new Random();
    }

    public boolean getTile(final int x, final int y) {
        boolean canPaint = loaded[x][y];
        if (!canPaint && !loading[x][y]) {
            loading[x][y] = true;
            Timer timer = new Timer(random.nextInt(500),
                    new ActionListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            loaded[x][y] = true;
                            repaint(x * TILE_SIZE, y * TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
                        }
                    });
            timer.setRepeats(false);
            timer.start();
        }
        return canPaint;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Rectangle clip = g.getClipBounds();
        int startX = clip.x - (clip.x % TILE_SIZE);
        int startY = clip.y - (clip.y % TILE_SIZE);
        for (int x = startX; x < clip.x + clip.width; x += TILE_SIZE) {
            for (int y = startY; y < clip.y + clip.height; y += TILE_SIZE) {
                if (getTile(x / TILE_SIZE, y / TILE_SIZE)) {
                    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                } else {
                    g.setColor(Color.RED);
                }
                g.fillRect(x, y, TILE_SIZE - 1, TILE_SIZE - 1);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
        return new Dimension(visibleTiles * TILE_SIZE, visibleTiles * TILE_SIZE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
        return TILE_SIZE * Math.max(1, visibleTiles - 1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
        return TILE_SIZE;
    }
}
```